# Safari 15.0 error message: "A problem repeatedly occurred:" Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: safari, catalina

I have had no problems with Safari until recently on my home Mac.   The identical Mac at the office does not suffer this error messageAttempts to visit certain websites ( banks, etc.) produce the error:

[image]

Home Depot:

[image]

Google returns articles and videos that suggest toggling settings or clearing caches (this does not work, nor did I expect it to), however, they do not provide for diagnosing the root cause of the problem with a procedure and a "litmus test" (observable evidence confirming root cause). An example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAiBIbl66mc

Is there a procedure to diagnose confirm that there is not a problem with the version of Safari and that there is something I did to put Safari in its current state?

Comment: This happened to me after one of the security updates on Catalina (I'm behind one version).  On many well known sites, the pages would repeatedly reload until the error message appeared.  @btf reinstall suggestion fixed it for me.  If anyone is curious, my log is filled with grumbles about `StagedFrameworks/Safari`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling Safari 15.0 solved this problem for me:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253165554

The link to download the .pkg to reinstall is:

http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/15/01/002-02859-A_TFTOEP7KTW/c962h7kwercno4bxxaql4o2g03y80pefij/Safari15.0CatalinaAuto.pkg

Answer (score 2):

Tested on operating systems Catalina, BigSur and Monterey. Please, read all answer because there are updates.

Today I solved this using macOS Monterey at an old MBP mid 2012 (yes, MBP 2012 with Monterey ) and Safari 16.1, I thing that you can try for another MacOS versions with few adjustments.

BACKUP your system before try this and IF you are a noobie or rookie and don't understand what I wrote below, please stop here!

First of all, you MUST download a safari installer, I recommend your start for here https://mrmacintosh.com/macos-safari-full-installer-database-download-directly-from-apple/.

Go to ADMIN account at Mac (you must be at this account, usually it account created during first installation).

STOP all safari processes using activity monitor (search for safari processes, usually 5 processes are running).

At finder or a terminal window search for directories:

/Library/Apple/System/Library/StageFrameworks/Safari
/Library/Apple/System/Library/Assistant/Plugins/Safari.assistantBundle

Delete them!

Search for files at /Library/Apple/System/Library/Receipts/

- com.apple.pkg.Safari16.0MontereyAuto.bom
- com.apple.pkg.Safari16.0MontereyAuto.plist
- com.apple.pkg.Safari16.1MontereyAutoSeed.bom
- com.apple.pkg.Safari16.1MontereyAutoSeed.plist
- com.apple.pkg.Safari16.1MontereySeed.bom
- com.apple.pkg.Safari16.1MontereySeed.plist
- com.apple.pkg.SafariTechPreview.bom
- com.apple.pkg.SafariTechPreview.plist

The files can be different because it depends on your Safari versions installed or updated. Delete all files like this!

Now, you can reinstall your downloaded Safari!

I hope this helps you.

If you are using OpenCore Legacy Patcher, please check UPDATE 3 before attempting the steps above.

UPDATE 1:
After first reply, now I included a website to download safari and indicated where the directories and files are located. Thx, Andy Griffiths to request this.

UPDATE 2:
Sometimes steps above will not working. In this cases, unfortunately, you need put your MacOS installer at the Application folders and then start reinstall process. It's annoying, tedious and frustrating, but you don't lost your files, only waste your time and Safari will working again! After all, don't try update Safari if Update Software recommends.

UPDATE 3 (IN 2023): The error occurred after updating iMac late 2012 to Monterey (12.6.6) and updating Safari (16.5) using OpenCore Legacy Patcher. I solved the issue. Please try the following steps:

0. Open OpenCore.
1. Click on "Post Install Root Patch".
2. Then, click on "Revert Root Patches".
3. Reboot your system.
4. Open OpenCore again.
5. Click on "Post Install Root Patch" once more.
6. Finally, click on "Reinstall Root Patches".
7. Reboot your system again.

Comment: Answers telling the OP to go and Google stuff you don't remember, or to search the filesystem for things, are not really a good example for an answer. You will need to make your answer more comprehensive and with a worked example, or it stands the risk of being downvoted because it cannot be verified that the answer is correct. Please try to improve your answer. Welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: Thank you Carlos, that works great (iMac 2013 Monterey)

Answer (score 1):

Had identical Javascript misbehavior on a 2012 5,1 Mac Pro after installing OCLP 0.6.7 with Monterey 12.6.7 and Safari 16.5.1.

I don’t know why WebKit (or whatever part of system) failed to run correctly when nothing else seemed wrong with the system, but these steps to revert and then reinstall Root Patches cured it:

1. Launch OpenCore-Patcher
2. Click ‘Post Install Root Patch’
3. Click ‘Revert Root Patches’
4. When finished, answer the dialog box to reboot
5. Login and launch OpenCore-Patcher
6. Click ‘Post Install Root Patch’
7. Click ‘Reinstall Root Patches’
8. When finished, answer the dialog box to reboot